# I have to get daily incoming and outgoing call history in Android

Tags: android

I have created call history app but I can't manage call date. On the other hand daily incoming and outgoing calls (Monday: 23 incoming and 12: Outgoing, .....)

Comment: using service and intent, catch the outgoing,incoming call.

Comment: But how can i do this.I got all call logs but i need daily